# What's the syntax for oop nusoap_client call?

Tags: php, soap, nusoap

I don't find the syntax for an object oriented nusoap_client call:

What's the correct syntax if I registered a class method to the server. I know the code for the server but fail to implement the correct client.

I have this server:

```
<?php

require_once "lib/nusoap.php"; 
require_once 'SampleData.php';

class SoapServer {

    protected $server;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->server = new soap_server();
        $server->register("SampleData.getSampleData");
        $server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

    }     
}
?>
```

How do I call this from my SoapClient?

```
    $result = $this->client->call("SampleData.getSampleData", array("category" => "sample"));
```

Seems not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would avoid using SoapServer as a class name, may conflict with the standard extension ([PHP Manual SoapServer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php)).

Why are you wrapping soap_server with SoapServer anyway? Instead try:

```
$server = new soap_server();
$server->register("SampleData.getSampleData");
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
```

Client call should be like this:

```
$client = new soapclient('URL');
$result = $client->call("SampleData.getSampleData", array("category" => "sample"));
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

//Define the client

$client = new soapclient('http:webservice.com');

//call the method
$result=$client->call('method',array('param1,param2'));